# How can I remove ‘flathub’ found in multiple installations?

Tags: flatpak

When I install a flathub app, using the terminal,
the following message appears:

flatpak install flathub org.libretro.RetroArch
Looking for matches…
Remote ‘flathub’ found in multiple installations:

1. system
2. user

Which do you want to use (0 to abort)? [0-2]: 1

Should I **erase** one of these flathub installations,
and how?